# Porque en visual studio code me dice que 'pip' no se reconoce como un cmdlet?

Tags: python, get, pip, studio, visual

Al ingresar en la terminall de visual studio code el comando pip, me manda un error donde dice que pip no se reconoce como un cmdlet, aunque ya en la terminal de windows ya haya instalado el comando pip

Comment: Prueba a usar `python -m pip install`

Comment: A mi sigue si funcionarme una vez que realizo en el terminal: python -m pip install